# sub relative cell complex

Tags: ct.category-theory, homotopy-theory, model-categories

This is a question concerning the proposition 11.4.8 of P.Hirschhorn's book [Model categories and their localizations](https://web.math.rochester.edu/people/faculty/doug/otherpapers/pshmain.pdf).

The proposition 11.4.8 is an analogous, in my opinion, to the well known statement in the topological spaces case : every cell of a cell complex is contained in a finite subcomplex of the cell complex.

Let me state the proposition first:

> Let $\mathcal M$ be a cofibrantly generated model category in which cofibrations are monomorphisms. If $\gamma$ is a cardinal and $K$ is a set of cofibrations whose domains are $\gamma-$compact, then every $K-$cell of a relative $K-$cell complex is contained in a sub relative $K-$cell complex of size at most $\gamma$.
>
> PROOF: Let $f:X\rightarrow Y$ be a relative $K-$cell complex, then we can write $f$ as the transfinite composition of a $\lambda-$sequence $X=X_0\rightarrow X_1\rightarrow X_1\rightarrow X_2\rightarrow \cdots\rightarrow X_{\beta}\rightarrow\cdots(\beta<\lambda)$ in which each map $X_{\beta}\rightarrow X_{\beta+1}$ is a pushout of an element of $K$. We will show by induction on $\beta$ that the attaching map of each $K-$cell factors through a sub relative $K-$cell complex of size at most $\gamma$. The induction is begun because the attaching map of the $K-$cell of presentation ordinal $1$ has codomain $X=X_0$.
>
> We now assume that $\alpha < \gamma $ and that every $K-$cell of $X\rightarrow X_{\alpha}$ is contained in a subcomplex of size at most $\gamma$. Let $C\rightarrow D$ be an element of $K$ such that $X_{\alpha+1}$ is constructed as the pushout $$\begin{array}
>   x C&{\longrightarrow}&D\\
>  \downarrow{h^{\alpha}}&& \downarrow \\
> X_{\alpha}&{\longrightarrow}&X_{\alpha+1}
> \end{array}
> $$
>   we must show that $h^{\alpha} $ factors through a sub relative $K-$cell complex of size at most $\gamma$. By a previous lemma, we can find a diagram $$\begin{array}
> AX_0 &\stackrel{\sigma_0}\longrightarrow & X_1&\stackrel{\sigma_1}{\longrightarrow} & X_2&\stackrel{\sigma_2}{\longrightarrow}&\cdots& \longrightarrow &X_{\alpha}
> \\
>  \downarrow{i_0}&& \downarrow{i_1}&&\downarrow{i_2}&&&&\downarrow{i_{\alpha}} 
> \\
> \tilde{X_0} &\stackrel{\tau_0}\longrightarrow & \tilde{X_1}&\stackrel{\tau_1}{\longrightarrow} & \tilde{X_2}&\stackrel{\tau_2}{\longrightarrow}&\cdots &\longrightarrow &\tilde{X_{\alpha}}
> \\
> \downarrow{r_0}&& \downarrow{r_1}&&\downarrow{r_2}&&&&\downarrow{r_{\alpha}} 
> \\
> X_0 &\stackrel{\sigma_0}\longrightarrow & X_1&\stackrel{\sigma_1}{\longrightarrow} & X_2&\stackrel{\sigma_2}{\longrightarrow}&\cdots& \longrightarrow &X_{\alpha}
> \end{array}$$
>   such that $r_{\beta}i_\beta=1_{X_{\beta}}$ for $\beta\leqslant \alpha $ and every $\tau_{\beta}$ is a relative $I-$cell complex (As usual, $I$ is the set of generating cofibrations).  Thus the composition $\tilde{X_0}\rightarrow \tilde{X_\alpha}$ is a relative $I-$cell complex, and so the composition $i_{\alpha}h^{\alpha}:C\rightarrow \tilde{X_{\alpha}}$ must factor through some sub relative $I-$cell complex $\tilde{X_0}\rightarrow V$ of $\tilde{X_0}\rightarrow \tilde{X_{\alpha}}$ of size at most $\gamma$. We will complete the proof by showing that the composition $V\rightarrow \tilde{X_{\alpha}}\rightarrow X_{\alpha}$ factors through a sub relative $K-$cell complex of $X_0\rightarrow X_{\alpha}$ of size at most $\gamma$.
>
> For each $I-$cell of $V$ there is exactly one $\beta\leqslant \alpha$ such that that cell is a part of $\tau_{\beta}$, and (by the induction hypothesis) the corresponding relative $K-$cell $\sigma_{\beta}:X_{\beta}\rightarrow X_{\beta+1}$ is contained in a sub relative $K-$cell complex of $X_0\rightarrow X_{\alpha}$ of size at most $\gamma$. If we take the union $Z$ of these sub relative $K-$cell complexes, then the relative $K-$cell complex $X_0\rightarrow Z$ has size at most $\gamma$, and the composition $V\rightarrow \tilde{X_{\alpha}}\rightarrow X_{\alpha}$ factors through the inclusion $Z\rightarrow X_{\alpha}$.

My question is: how to prove the last sentence of the proof:

> the composition $V\rightarrow \tilde{X_{\alpha}}\rightarrow X_{\alpha}$ factors through the inclusion $Z\rightarrow X_{\alpha}$.

The proof is a little bit long and we can just start from the third paragraph 'For each $I-$cell of $V$ there is exactly one ...'

PS: I want to apply this proposition to the case when the model category is compactly generated in the sense of Bertrand Toen (cf. Moduli of Objects In DG-categories Definition 2.1.4 ) : each $I-$cell of an $I-$cell complex is contained in a strict finite sub $I-$cell complex and hence every object is weak equivalent to a filtered colimit of strict finite $I-$cell complexes.